# $ \forall x\in X~,~\exists\phi_x\in\mathbb{R}~,~ \phi_x=\lim_{n} f_n(x) $?

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $H$ be a subset dense in $X $.

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a squence of function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is equicontinuous on $X$ such that:

$$
\forall x\in H~,~\exists\phi_x\in\mathbb{R}~,~ \phi_x=\lim_{n} f_n(x)
$$

Can we say that :
$$
\forall y\in X~,~\exists\phi_y\in\mathbb{R}~,~ \phi_y=\lim_{n} f_n(y)
$$

Comment: So your question is, if the equicontinuous sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise on a dense subset, must it converge on the whole space? What does the equicontinuity of $f_n$ at $y$ tell you?

Comment: $\{f_n\}$  is equicontinuous at $x$ iff  :$$ \forall \epsilon >0~,~\exists \gamma >0\text{ 
 such that } \forall y\in X\text{ with }\|x-y\|<\gamma \text{ we have : }|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon~,~ \forall n$$

Comment: I said equicontinuity at $y$ (to go along with your final expression you want to prove). Now given that there exist values of $x$ arbitarily close to $y$ for which $f_n(x)$ converges, can you figure out how to use that to estimate the behavior of $f_n(y)$?

Comment: no i can't    $~~~~$.

Comment: Note that for any $\epsilon$, there is $\gamma$ with $\|x - y\| < \gamma \implies |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon/3$, and note that since $H$ is dense, there are $x \in H$ with $\|x - y\| < \gamma$. And finally note that for such an $x, f_n(x)$ converges, which means it is Cauchy.